# Print star pattern based on coordinate

Tags: java

I am new to java, I want to print a reversed star pattern based on the coordinate. After I set the coordinate, it will then print the star pattern

[image: This is the expected and how to do it]

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class coorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max = 5;
        for (int y = 0; y < max; y += 2) {
            int left_spacing = (int) Math.floor(y * 1.0 / 2.0);

            for (int space = 0; space < left_spacing; space++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < (max - y); x++) {
                System.out.print("x");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you have any issue? What is the problem we can help you resolve? What exactly, and precisely are you asking us to help you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I am using (0,0) as a first coordinate.

```
public static void printStar(int x, int y) {
    int starCount = 5;
    int space = 0;
    int count = 0;

    // y-axis line move
    for(int i=0; i<y; i++) {
        System.out.println();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < starCount; i++) {

        // x-axis space move
        for(int xAxis=0; xAxis<x; xAxis++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < starCount; j++) {
            if (count < space) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                count++;
                continue;
            } else if (j >= starCount - count) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        space++;
        count = 0;
    }
}
```